# Convertir array a array de objeto

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, javascript-objeto

Poseo un array de esta forma:

```
var arr= ["AVI","MP4","MPEG"]
```

y necesito dejarlo como array de objeto:

```
 var mo = [
     { text:'AVI', value:'AVI' },
     { text:'MP4', value:'MP4' },
     { text:'MPEG', value:'MPEG' }        
 ]
```

La idea es poder usarlo para opciones de checkbox de bootstrap vue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así, usando el [método `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) de la clase Array para generar un nuevo array:

```js
var arr= ["AVI","MP4","MPEG"]
 var mo = arr.map(x=> { return {text:x, value:x}})
 console.log(mo)
```

Comment: me funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Que tal si agregas una explicacion

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de realizarlo iterando sobre el array:

Agregando cada elemento en un nuevo array

```js
 var arr= ["AVI","MP4","MPEG"]
   
let mo = []

for (item in arr) {
  mo.push({
text: arr[item],
value: arr[item]
  })

}

console.log(mo)
```

---

Usando el método map de esta forma:

```js
 var arr= ["AVI","MP4","MPEG"]
   
let mo = Object.keys(arr).map((item) => {
  return {
    text: arr[item],
    value: arr[item]
  }
})

console.log(mo)
```